# Jsp and servlet error with getAttribute of the user after login

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

```
<% Cliente currentUser = (Cliente) session.getAttribute("username"); %>
<h2>   Username <%= currentUser.getUsername()   %></h2>
```

I want to take the username of the user once I've logged in. How can i solve or fix the servlet login?

This is the servlet login, What is the problem that does not make me save the username after login?

```
@WebServlet("/Login")
public class Login extends HttpServlet {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public Login() {
        super();
    }

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        doPost(request, response);
    }

    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        String username = request.getParameter("username");
        String pass = request.getParameter("password");
        try {
            Utente utente = (Utente) Query.TrovaCliente(username, pass);
            if (utente == null) {
                request.getRequestDispatcher("loginError.jsp").forward(request, response);
            } else {
                HttpSession session = request.getSession();
                synchronized (session) {
                    session.setAttribute("utente", utente);
                }
                request.getRequestDispatcher("index.jsp").forward(request, response);
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            request.getRequestDispatcher("loginError.jsp").forward(request, response);
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `currentUser` is `null`. That's why you get this error

Comment: @MaruthiAdithya once logged in, I want to take the username of the user who is logged in. How can i do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure you can cast the session attribute "username" to `Cliente`?

```
<% Cliente currentUser = (Cliente) session.getAttribute("username"); %>
<h2>   Username <%= currentUser.getUsername()   %></h2> // <-- here you get a NullPointer
```

which means, that `currentUser` is `null` and you can't call any function on it.
Maybe you could first printout what you actually have in your session

```
<h2> session attribute: <%=session.getAttribute("username"); %> </h2>
```

to make sure that the session actually contains that attribute you are looking for and that it can be cast to a `Cliente` object.

**EDIT**

From what I can see you set the whole object `utente` (which I guess is your user object) in your session with the key `"utente"`. The attribute `"username"` is still not present.

What you could do is

```
 <% Utente currentUser = (Utente ) session.getAttribute("utente"); %>
 <h2>   Username <%= currentUser.getUsername()   %></h2>
```

if the class `Utente` has a `getUsername` method.

Comment: The result of <h2> session attribute: <%=session.getAttribute("username") %> </h2> is : null. How can i take the username of the current user?

Comment: make sure that at login, the username is actually stored in the session.

Comment: I have add the servlet login in the question.